# timepicker is not displaying drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have recently starting playing around with html and css, and I am stuck with time selector.
Basically, I am creating a form for my website which includes selecting time and date. My date selector works fine (it diplays the calender), however my time selector drop-down does not do anything at all. I have tried many solution but none has worked yest. When i pasted my code to snippet i got following error;

> $()... time-picker is not a function

I have tried many solutions, including adding bootstrap.min.js and jquery-1.11.1.min.js as suggested in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631402/timepicker-is-not-a-function-when-using-timepicker-js) but no luck.

Many Thanks,
Hassam

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
 $( "#timepicker" ).timepicker();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="styleshee" type="text/css" href="jquery.timepicker.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontAwesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hero-slider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooplate-style.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="new.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="hr-timePicker.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src ="script.js"></script> 
       
    </head>
    <body>
            
            <div class = "bgImage">
                   
           <form>
                    
                      <div class="formWrap">
                        <p class = "text">Please Enter Your details</p>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname*" required autofocus />
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname*" required />
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email*" required />
                        <input type="text" class="js--datePicker" id="datepicker1" value="Date*">     
                        <input id="timepicker" class = "timepicker" name="datetime" type="text" required>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
                        
    </body>

</html>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Timepicker is an external library. Check the head section on the link you provided. Try referencing the `jquery.timepicker.js` library from `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-timepicker` after your jquery link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code to use absolute reference to timepicker js code in a cdn using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
```

and added the following before your `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the working snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
});

$(function() {
  $('#timepicker').timepicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="styleshee" type="text/css" href="jquery.timepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontAwesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hero-slider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooplate-style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="bgImage">

    <form>

      <div class="formWrap">
        <p class="text">Please Enter Your details</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname*" required autofocus />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname*" required />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email*" required />
        <input type="text" class="js--datePicker" id="datepicker1" value="Date*">
        <input id="timepicker" class="timepicker" name="datetime" type="text" required>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, jfeferman, 
Thankyou for your quick response, your code snippet is working perfectly fine, but when i run it on waterfox it still doesn't show any drop-down!